# Physical microscopic origin of vapor pressure and relation to bond strength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, vacuum, evaporation, elements

Currently, I am examining the vapor pressure of the elements as a function of temperature within the periodic table (as can be found from this resource from TU Wien https://www.iap.tuwien.ac.at/www/surface/vapor_pressure), and I am specifically interested in the physical origin of why some elements like tungsten have much lower vapor pressures than other solid elements like Sulfer or Phosphorus. This in turn means that a sample of tungsten must be heated to significantly higher temperatures to reach the same vapor pressure in a vacuum chamber compared to a sample of Sulfer.

I imagine the reason for this relates to the bond strength of the element in question (which can be characterised through the enthalpy of vaporisation), since I know that tungsten has a very high bond strength due to its metallic nature, but I am unsure about the validity of that since Carbon, which has a very low vapor pressure, has a comparable enthalpy of vaporisation to Iron, which has a comparatively higher vapor pressure.

So in short, what the is the physical microscopic origin of the vapor pressure of a material and how does this relate to the bond strength?

Comment: I'll just point out that lead is metallic in nature, yet does not have a 'high bond strength' because of that.

Comment: Enthalpies of vaporization: iron 350 kJ/mol, carbon 715 kJ/mol, tungsten 800 kJ/mol. So I don’t understand why you’ve ordered things the way you have in your question. What numbers are you using?

Comment: @Chemomechanics I am using the numbers as quoted here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization

Comment: @JonCuster Because of what?

Comment: Because of the ‘metallic nature’ of the bonding. Plenty of low melting elements.

Comment: @tjsmert44 I don't know where that number comes from; there's no reference. Referenced values are [here](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7440440&Units=SI&Mask=1#Thermo-Gas).

Answer (score 0):

The equilibrium vapor pressure (assuming an ideal gas, which is reasonable for the low vapor pressure of most condensed matter) is

$$p = p_0\exp\left(-\frac{\mu_\mathrm{G}-\mu_\mathrm{S}}{RT}\right),$$

where $p_0$ is 1 atm, $\mu_\mathrm{G}$ and $\mu_\mathrm{S}$ are respectively the chemical potentials of the gas and solid phases of the temperature and pressure of interest, $R$ is the gas constant, and $T$ is the temperature. (Here, I've used the [fugacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugacity) definition $\mu=\mu_0+RT\ln( f/p_0)$ where $\mu_0$ is a reference value and assumed ideality to approximation the fugacity $f$ with $p$.)

In addition, $\mu\equiv h-Ts$ by definition, where $h$ is the molar enthalpy and $s$ is the molar entropy, giving

$$p = p_0\exp\left(-\frac{\Delta h_{\mathrm{GS}}}{RT}\right)\exp\left(\frac{\Delta s_{\mathrm{GS}}}{R}\right),$$

where the subscript GS represents the gas phase relative to the solid phase. The vapor pressure of condensed matter thus arises from the entropy increase from forming the gas phase. Under this framework, a smaller bond strength $h$ doesn't suppress the vapor pressure as much.